# How to Filter Shiny App Dataset using a Regular Expression Regex

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

I'm super new to Shiny Apps and to R. How would I add a button that allows me to filter the passed-in dataset using this regex? The uploaded dataset would all contain the same column names, and the column I want to apply the regex to is "close_notes" Thank you so much for your help in advance!

`"\\bMASTER DATA\\b|\\bSOURCE LIST\\b|\\bVALIDITY DATES\\b|\\bMRP CONTROLLER\\b|\\bPSV\\b|\\bELIGIBILITY\\b|\\bCOST\\b|\\bMARKETING EXCLUSION\\b|\\bEFFECTIVITY\\b|\\bMISSING\\b|\bbBLANK\\b"`

The code below is for the Shiny App. Please let me know if anything looks wrong or like it should be modified. Thank you!

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                      accept = c(
                          "text/csv",
                          "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                          ".csv")
            ),
            tags$hr(),
            checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
            
            # Button
            downloadButton("downloadData", "Download")
            
        ),
        mainPanel(
            dataTableOutput("contents")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    datasetInput <- reactive({
        req(input$file1)
        # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
        # and uploads a file, it will be a data frame with 'name',
        # 'size', 'type', and 'datapath' columns. The 'datapath'
        # column will contain the local filenames where the data can
        # be found.
        inFile <- input$file1
        
        if (is.null(inFile))
            return(NULL)
        
        read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header)
    })
    
    output$contents <- renderDataTable({
        datasetInput()
    })
    
    output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
        filename = function() {
            paste("myfile",Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep = "")
        },
        content = function(file) {
            write.csv(datasetInput(), file, row.names = FALSE)
        }
    )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: It's not clear what the uploaded dataset looks like, so it is not clear what to filter. Also, it appears that this problem is solely about applying a regex to some dataset, regardless of presence in `shiny`. Can you get it to work on the console? If not, then I suggest you simplify your problem to just a sample dataset (`data.frame`?) and your regex.

Comment: The uploaded dataset will all be the same column names, and I need this regex applied to the column called "close_notes". How could I do that? Thank you for your help!